# warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file 'doc_code_file1' will be installed to the per user directory 'code_Simple'

Tags: wix

Eventhough I addded the registry value settings. It gives the following warning

```
warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file 'doc_code_file1' will be installed to the per user directory 'code_Simple' that doesn't vary based on ALLUSERS value
. This file won't be copied to each user's profile even if a per machine installation is desired
```

My Code

```
<Component Id='doc_code_copy' Guid='DA95057C-9866-4422-B00B-105BBF862C92' Directory='code_Simple'>
      <RegistryKey Root='HKCU' Key='Software\SimpleToolkit_2012\uninstall\Codesnipet'>
            <RegistryValue Value='Installed code snipet in Document' Type='string' KeyPath='yes'></RegistryValue>
        </RegistryKey>

      <File Id='doc_code_file1' Name='doc_code_file1' DiskId='1'
            Source='Personalfolder\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\command.snippet' />
   </Component>
</Directory>
```

How can suppress this warning ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to suppress the warning you can add `-sice:ICE91` to the `light.exe` command-line to prevent that particular ICE from running. Alternatively, you can add to your .wixproj a property like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SuppressIces>ICE91</SuppressIces>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you are using Visual Studio to open your .wixproj files, you can set that property by going to the `Project Properties` on the `Tool Settings` tab, you can add `ICE91` there.

Comment: where should i add -sice:ICE91? I'm getting confused. Please help me

Comment: Sorry, updated answer to be more clear and added details about Votive.

Comment: @RobMensching How can i suppress LGHT1072 warnings? How can i suppress warnings other than ICE in VS2008? Please help me.