# What does warning "warning LGHT1076 : ICE91" mean?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have per user installation.
Application will be installed to user's AppData directory.
There is following warning during build of wxs file:

```
warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file 'app.exe' will be installed to the per user directory 'INSTALLDIR' that doesn't vary based on ALLUSERS value. 
This file won't be copied to each user's profile even if a per machine installation is desired.
```

What does it mean that file won't be copied to user's profile?
As I can see my application is isntalled without any problems. File is installed to user's AppData directory.

Comment: For any ICE warning, you should be able to find a page relating to it by searching `ice msi <number>`. [So...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369053(v=vs.85).aspx): "These warnings are harmless if the package is only used for installation in the per-user installation context and never used for per-machine installations."

Comment: I see you've seen his other question.  He's attempting to do per-user/per-machine.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when you install a file to a user profile location and another user uses the app in a per machine install, you want all the files there. Otherwise you have an app that works for the installing user (because the file is there in the user profile folder) but it won't work for other users because the file is missing. If the MSI file was built "correctly", another user would log on, use a shortcut (for example) and Windows would notice the missing file and install it, therefore every user account (even those that are not yet created) will get a copy of the file in their user profile folder. If you're doing a per machine install and you want every user (not just you!) to get a copy of the file you should fix it.

Comment: How can you fix it? How can you do a per machine install and ensure that every user gets a copy of the file?

Comment: It's the shortcut, as I try to explain. Using a shortcut triggers a check that the files in that feature are installed, and for another user they won't be, so there'll be a request for the original MSI to install the missing file.

Answer (score 1):

> CE91 posts a warning if a file, .ini file, or shortcut file is
>   installed into a per-user only directory. These warnings are harmless
>   if the package is only used for installation in the per-user
>   installation context and never used for per-machine installations.

You may wanna take a [look into the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369053(VS.85).aspx).

If you want to suppress that warning msg take a look into [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121759/warning-lght1076-ice91-the-file-doc-code-file1-will-be-installed-to-the-per)